# How to get the row from an actioncolumn handler

Tags: extjs, extjs4

Question says it all.  I need to get the DOM node of the row that contains the clicked item in an actioncolumn.

It seems like it would be easy since I have the rowIndex but there's nothing in the docs that suggests how to use that to get the row.  Nothing reasonably obvious at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use getNode: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-2/#!/api/Ext.grid.View

`grid.getView().getNode(rowIndex);`

Comment: Thanks.  Why is so hard to find something that simple in the Ext docs?  GOD!